# Ant colony in Zero Gravity

Tags: civilization, infrastructure, microgravity

The image below is an Ant colony in the glass chamber. If the Ants in Chamber filled with soil can generate such structure of colonies. What would happen if the Ants are kept in the same chamber but in Zero Gravity Condition? What will the shape of the ant colony?

There is a NASA articles on the Study of Ants in space for collecting collection on resources. https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/news/ants_in_space/

[image: Ant Colony on earth]

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As the name suggests, we solve worldbuilding problems. What is the worldbuilding problem here? I see a question which is already answer by a real world study. More info about our scope in the [help]

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica The question is not answered by any existing study (that I was able to find).  The "ants in space" link provided by OP pertains only to the search behavior of ants in zero G, they were not provided with dirt to dig in.  I agree that the question was not framed in a world building context though, hopefully OP can edit it to provide some context.  Without that context the answer would seem to be, "The dirt would just float around, tunnels would not be stable."

Answer (score 1):

> what shape will the ant colony take?

The ants will start building vertically, they can already do that, but it's rare, and difficult because the soil falls directly on the insects pushing them down.